# Transcendental number over $\{k\in K\mid f(k)=k\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $f:K\rightarrow K$ be a ring endomorphism. Prove that if $\alpha\in K\setminus f(K)$, then $\alpha$ is transcendental over the subfield of $K$, $F:=\{k\in K\mid f(k)=k\}$.

*My proof:* $\alpha$ is transcendental over $F$ iff doesn't exist $0\neq p(x)\in F[x]$ such that $p(\alpha)=0$. Suppose such $p(x)$ exists, say $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n b_ix^i$, with $b_i\in F$ not all $0$. We know that $f$ is injective, so $f^{-1}(0)$ is well defined and
$$f^{-1}(0)=f^{-1}(p(\alpha))=\sum_{i=0}^n b_i f^{-1}(\alpha)^i.$$
But $\alpha\not\in f(K)$, so the last summation is not defined, absurd.

Can you check my proof please? I'm not so sure, because the same argument works also with any subfield of $f(K)$ instead of $F$...

Comment: Your definition of transcendental is wrong. Repeat it, and watch out for the zero polynomial. Besides, your whole proof does not make any sense since you calculate with something not defined (namely $f^{-1}(\alpha)$) and then conclude the claim ...?!

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: I've fixed the definition of transcendental, but I still don't understand why my proof is wrong. $f^{-1}(0)$ is well defined, and $\sum_{i=0}^n b_i f^{-1}(\alpha)^i$ is not, but they are equal. Isn't this a contradiction?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Martin is pointing out that $f^{-1}(0)$ has a simpler name ("zero"), but $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ doesn't make sense because $\alpha \not\in f(K)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is wrong as $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ has no meaning.

Instead you can use $f(\alpha)$: since $p(\alpha)=0$ and the coefficients of $p$ are fixed by $f$ you get (by applying $f$ to $p(\alpha)=0$) that $p(f(\alpha))=0$. Now iterate this and find $p(f^i(\alpha))=0$ for all $i\ge 0$, where $f^i$ denotes the $i$th composition of $f$ by itself. But $p$ can have only finitely many roots, so there exist $m<n$ such that $f^m(\alpha)=f^n(\alpha)$, that is, $f^{n-m}(\alpha)=\alpha$ (don't forget that $f$ is injective), so $\alpha\in f(K)$, a contradiction.